# Sound not working properly or consistent

Tags: raspbian, audio, pi-3b+, hdmi

I have a Pi 3b+ and having issues with sound.  I have tried raspi-config as well as altering the config.txt for HDMI2.

First I was getting sound when playing file throught VLC using headphone jack but not in Chromium.

Now I get audio in chromium using headphone jack but not VLC.

I have tried several times to us it over HDMI by plugging speaker into back of monitor but despite forcing audio to HDMI using raspi-config and the uncommenting the HDMI2 in the config file.

Any ideas on how to get sound through HDMI and consistently from all sources?

Comment: What does " to us it over" mean? Have you installed any system audio libraries (like Pulse/Jack) or do you have pure ALSA?

Comment: Uninstall pulseaudio and everything will magically start working again.